# Customise for-loops in function arguments (in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by

My colleague has written 8 similar functions for performing an operation after filtering. As an example, one function is like

```
def operation_at_country_kind_level(df):
    # there are other countries in the data,
    # but we only want these two hardcoded ones
    for country in ["USA", "UK"]:
        # again, hardcoded values for kind
        for kind in ["A", "B"]:
            df_filter = df[(df["Country"] == country) & (df["Kind"] == kind)]
            results = operation(df_filter)
            store_results(results, country = country, kind = kind)
```

and another is like

```
def operation_at_country_level(df):
    for country in ["USA", "UK"]:
        df_filter = df[df["Country"] == country]
        results = operation(df_filter)
        store_results(results, country = country, kind = "-")
```

There's also a function with no filtering at all, it just computes the results from the input data frame and has `store_results(results, country = "-", type = "-")` as the final call. In the real data there are 4 columns that the user can choose to filter on.

I want to simplify this by just having one function and the user passes in arguments for the filtering levels they need. My thought is to use a group-by statement, like in the example below, which features some pseudo-code

```
def operation_at_level(df, groupby_columns):
    # check if we're doing any for loop
    if len(groupby_columns) > 0:
        for index, data in df.groupby(groupby_columns):
           # check that the values in the index are
           # valid, something like 'if "Country" in 
           # groupby_columns and index[index_of_country_
           # in_groupby_columns] in ["USA", "UK"]'
           results = operation(data)
           store_results(results, # work out what should
           # go here based on groupby columns)
    else:
        results = operation(df)
        store_results(results, "-", "-")
```

It feels like I have so many checks inside the function that it's just as much effort as having 8 different functions. Any suggestions for how to merge these similar functions with 4 possible columns to filter on into one function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use boolean mask before group by columns:

```
import numpy as np

filters = {
    'country': ['USA', 'UK'],
    'kind': ['A', 'B']
}

def operation_at_level(df, groupby_columns):
    if len(groupby_columns) > 0:
        m = np.logical_and.reduce([df[col].isin(filters[col])
                                   for col in groupby_columns
                                   if col in filters])
        df_filter = df[m]          
        print(df_filter)                 
        # the rest of your code here
        ...
```

Demo:

```
>>> operation_at_level(df, ['country', 'kind'])
   country kind  value
6      USA    A     65
9      USA    A     43
10     USA    A     32
12      UK    A     10
13      UK    B     74

>>> operation_at_level(df, ['country'])
   country kind  value
6      USA    A     65
7      USA    C     87
8      USA    C     56
9      USA    A     43
10     USA    A     32
11      UK    C     16
12      UK    A     10
13      UK    B     74
14      UK    C     85
```

Minimal Working Example:

```
>>> df
   country kind  value
0       IN    A     10
1       IN    C     23
2       IN    A     26
3       IN    B     46
4       IN    A     21
5       IN    B     34
6      USA    A     65
7      USA    C     87
8      USA    C     56
9      USA    A     43
10     USA    A     32
11      UK    C     16
12      UK    A     10
13      UK    B     74
14      UK    C     85
```

Comment: Excellent idea to do the filtering step first

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getattr` function to get the function you want each time by hyving the user give the name of the function he wants to use and then call that function.

e.g.

```
import funcs  # Suppose your file with all the functions is called funcs
func_to_call = input("Tell me which function you want to use:")
function = getattr(funcs  , func_to_call )
result = function(df)
```

Otherwise, you could probably pass an extra argument and use it to map/ check with ifs which function you want to call.

```
def global_operation_filter(df, check):
    if check == 1:
        # write the code for the first check
    if check == 2:
        # write the code for the second check etc
```

Comment: +1 thanks Orfeas, that's useful to know. In this case, the main problem for me is not that a user has to use different names for each function, but that having the collection of similarly defined functions violates the DRY principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself If I want to, e.g., change an input parameter for the `operation` function then I'll have to go through and amend all 8 of them, and potentially I'll miss something or make a mistake. I should have made that clearer in the question